# Emmet, Visual Code, JSX and CSS not working together

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, emmet

So for some reason only part of Emmet is working in my ReactJS files. I am currently working on adding the CSS to some of these files and I can't seem to get it working properly.

When I type m-10, which should normally translate to margin: 10px, it actually translates to:
`<m-10></m-10>`

Has anyone even had a simular problem? Maybe some of my setting are wrong or maybe it has to do with the fact I am using styled components and their backtics.

If anyone knows a solution, or knows what I am doing wrong, please let me know.

I already added:
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
"javascript": "javascriptreact",
},

And most other abbreviations work without a problem, it's really only the CSS specific shortcuts that don't work.

UPDATE:
So I managed to "sort of" get it working yet there are still some bugs. I added "typescript": "typescriptreact" in my Emmet "emmet.includeLanguages" setting. Now I can actually select the right snippet but I have to manually activate Emmet (ctrl + space) and it is the second option, not the first.
Besides that, when I do select the correct snippet, it completes it like this:
 `m-margin: -10px;`
So that doesn't really help.